# Unique identifier always null in Windows Phone Mobile Services

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8, azure-mobile-services

I am running the following query and I successfully get all the records from the Alarms table:

```
List<Alarms> items = await App.MobileService.GetTable<Alarms>().OrderBy(item => item.AlarmDate).ToListAsync();
```

The only problem is that the identity field always appears as null (0), for every single row. Could this be a mapping problem? Is it something I am missing?

Here is the class that matches the table up in the cloud:

```
public class Alarms
{
    public int Id { get; set; }//problem must be here
    public int PatientId { get; set; }
    public string AlarmType { get; set; }
    public DateTime AlarmDate { get; set; }
    public string AlarmName { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

The column names here match the ones from the table up in the cloud. I triple checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
[DataContract(Name = "Alarms")]
public class Alarms
{
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "PatientId")]
    public int PatientId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "AlarmType")]
    public string AlarmType { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "AlarmDate")]
    public DateTime AlarmDate { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "AlarmName")]
    public string AlarmName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "IsEnabled")]
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kirill. I've tried your solution but I'm afraid it still doesn't work. It acts the same way as before.

Comment: Name property of DataMemberAttribute is the name of the column in the table (case sensitive).

Comment: Yes! It works now. I changed the identity field back to lowercase "id" on the database side. Apparently the identity field (always) has to be  lowercase "id". Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your ID property to be named "Id".  I believe the naming convention requires it to be upper case 'I' and lower case 'd'.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I changed it to "Id" in both places (database and mapping class) and I still have the same problem. It must be something else.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you changed it on the database?  You shouldn't have had to create anything on the database side as Mobile Services generates the id column (and other columns) for you.

Comment: I made the change using the Management Portal at manage.windowsazure.com. I simply renamed the "ID" to "Id" as you suggested.

Comment: I think you'll need to leave the column name AS IS in the database.  I was just saying to change the ID property in your Alarms class, not on the database side.  Sorry for the confusion.  Try resetting that column or regenerating your table.

Comment: I understand what you mean. Right now it is "Id" on both sides (database and C# code - Alarm class). Before it was "ID" in both places as well. I was aware of consistency from the very beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Guid id or primary key is not supported in azure mobile services.
But if a table has Guid column other than primary key, then you can get those guids after fixing azure mobile service sdk.

I updated the Azure Mobile Services SDK to fix the issue with GUID/uniqueidentifiers.
The code is on github. 
You can see my changes in Commits
https://github.com/vinodshinde/azure-mobile-services